# ColdFusion loop causes missing id's in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

Well, I found the problem.  It was not the loop per se.  It was the list.  Note the list has a blank after each comma.  I tend to do that for readability.  However, apparently CF honors that blank as a real part of the list item, which I did not know.  Removing the blanks in the list cured the problem.

I am using JavaScript to fill in some form elements.  The code below works, but is rather repetitive.  So I tried to turn it into a loop.  That failed in a peculiar way.  The working code:

```
<cfset textarr = getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterValues('rep2text')>

 <cfset valtitle = textarr[1]>
 <cfset valbef   = textarr[2]>
 <cfset valaft   = textarr[3]>
 <cfoutput>
     <script type = "text/Javascript">
        puttitle('#valtitle#',  'title')
        puttitle('#valbef#',    'summbef')
        puttitle('#valaft#',    'summaft') 
     </script>
 </cfoutput>
```

Here is `puttitle` (simplified for this example):

```
function puttitle(text, id ) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = text;
}
```

Since I have a lot more than three items I wanted to condense the code by doing it this way:

```
  <cfset txt = StructNew()>
  <cfset textarr = getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterValues('rep2text')>
  <cfset colidls   = "title, summbef, summaft"><!---these are the id's---> 
  <cfset i = 0>
  <cfloop list = "#colidls#" index = "item">
      <cfset i = i + 1>
      <cfset txt[item] = textarr[i]>

      <script type = "text/javascript">
         puttitle('#txt[item]#', '#item#')     
      </script>
  </cfloop>
```

This is much less code given the long lists of form values I pick up in `textarr`.  Further, if another item is added, all I have to do is put it into `colidls`, and the code will automatically do it's thing.

The problem I'm having with the loop approach is that it is not finding all the id's into which it is putting data.  It's finding some of them and properly placing the values where they should be. But it is not finding others, and when I checked they were indicated as null.

Since the first code sample without the loop works perfectly, the input fields with their id's must be properly formed.  I've checked that all the data is being transmitted properly to `textarr`, that `colidls` is exactly correct, and that `puttitle` is receiving what it should.

So I'm baffled.  Why are some of my id's turning up null?  Is there something sloppy in the code which needs to be tightened up?  Is there some subtlety of JavaScript I've missed?  Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Not everything you are doing is clear, but I suggest looking for a way to have your cfloop tag inside the script tag instead of the other way around.  Also, the use of any javascript at all might be an overcomplication of a simple task.

Comment: I agree with @DanBracuk and also fewer lines of code does not always mean cleaner, better, simpler code.

Comment: Can you include a dump of the `textarr` so we can see what the data looks like?

Comment: I've noted in an edit of the question that the problem was due to blank spaces in the list, and is cured by removing the blank spaces.  Dan, why is it better to put the loop tag inside the script tag?  I do want to assure you that the actual javascript function is more complex than my example above; I can't think of a way to pass info to a form without javascript.

Comment: Alex, I agree that fewer lines is not necessarily better.  In this case, the lists are rather long, and writing out each case individually is cumbersome.  The loop approach is a little harder to read, but probably easier to maintain, since the addition, change, or deletion of an item on the list requires just changing that one entry, instead of a whole block of code.